# google maps not showing properly and force close

Tags: android, google-maps

i tried every code and every question here to find error every time i fix something-something else break down and square boxes of grid cover all the map if i click on it all i need is while clicking on map draw mark and get address in textview using GPS and this output looks like **[this](http://s.joomeo.com/4f1c16283f061)** and i tested my internet connection to emulator and it works

here is logcat errors:

```
   01-23 03:37:52.868: E/MapActivity(309): Couldn't get connection factory client
   01-23 03:37:53.979: E/QemuSensors(309): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number
   01-23 03:37:53.979: E/QemuSensors(309): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number
   01-23 03:37:53.989: E/QemuSensors(309): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number
   01-23 03:37:53.989: E/QemuSensors(309): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number
```

here is code:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

MapView map = null;
long start;
long end;
MyLocationOverlay compass = null;
MapController c;
int x, y;
GeoPoint g;
Drawable d;
LocationManager n;
int lati = 0;
int longi = 0;
Customize cus;
Drawable drawable;
OverlayItem f;
Location location;
String add = "";
Criteria m;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapid);
    map.getController();
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setStreetView(true);
    map.getController().setZoom(19);
    // map.setTraffic(true);

    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

    map.getOverlays().add(new Customize(d));
    compass = new MyLocationOverlay(Map.this, map);
    map.getOverlays().add(compass);

    getLastLocation();

}

public void getLastLocation() {
    String provider = getBestProvider();
    location = n.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        setCurrentLocation(location);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location not yet acquired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.providerid)).setText("Provider :"
            + getBestProvider());

}

public String getBestProvider() {

    n = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    m = new Criteria();
    m.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    m.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    String bestProvider = n.getBestProvider(m, false);
    return bestProvider;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    compass.disableCompass();
    super.onPause();
    n.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    compass.enableCompass();
    super.onResume();
    n.requestLocationUpdates(getBestProvider(), 500, 1, this);
}

class maps extends Overlay {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        // ---when user lifts his finger---

        if (event.getAction() == 1) {
            g = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        g.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, g.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6,
                        1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0)
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(add);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    /*
     * public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
     * long when) {
     * 
     * try{ super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); //---translate the GeoPoint
     * to screen pixels--- g= new GeoPoint( (int) (lati * 1E6), (int) (longi
     * * 1E6)); Point screenPts = new Point();
     * mapView.getProjection().toPixels(g, screenPts); //---add the
     * marker--- Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(),
     * R.drawable.blue); canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50,
     * null); } catch(Exception h){
     * 
     * h.printStackTrace(); } finally{
     * 
     * map.setSatellite(!map.isSatellite());
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * 
     * return true; }
     */

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public void setCurrentLocation(Location location) {
    lati = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    longi = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    g = new GeoPoint(lati, longi);

    map.getOverlays().add(new Customize(drawable));

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

    setCurrentLocation(arg0);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Staus Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
}

public class Customize extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    ArrayList<OverlayItem> ar = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Drawable defaultMarker = null;

    public Customize(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        this.defaultMarker = defaultMarker;

        boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker);

        ar.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.748963847316034,
                -73.96807193756104), "UN", "United Nations"));
        ar.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.76866299974387,
                -73.98268461227417), "Lincoln Center",
                "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));
        ar.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.765136435316755,
                -73.97989511489868), "Carnegie Hall",
                "Where you go with practice, practice, practice"));
        ar.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.70686417491799,
                -74.01572942733765), "The Downtown Club",
                "Original home of the Heisman Trophy"));
        ar.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(lati, longi), " ", " "));

        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ar.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ar.size();
    }

    protected boolean onTap(int i) {

        Toast.makeText(Map.this, ar.get(i).getSnippet(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return (true);
    }

}
}
```

manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ShareActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Map" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.share.MAP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you post the `logcat` information as well?

Comment: sorry but ican't import my logcat here , can any body help me i tried evey thing !!

Comment: I read in some book that the 'force close' happens when an application is not responding quick enough (i think its 5 seconds). if that is the case, try to move the code that takes a lot of execution time and put it in another thread.

Comment: you are right i takes so much time in execution before launching and it's very weird, what do you mean by putting that code in another thread ??

Comment: i also tried another code on the map and it appear but when i clicked on it same square grid covers the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my map key *was wrong* and this was causing map not appearing with white grid

i needed to add **path of keytool in C drive** to my path that's

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel 
Items\System\Environment Variables
```

and use this command in cmd to get key

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "Path to your debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

and finally i got the correct key :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reducing your zoom level...probably zoom level 19 is not available in the location requested...did you try zooming to level 19 in googlemaps for the location requested???

If that is not the case please give more information...you can copy paste logs that can give some more details...

Comment: ok @Navin i did that i put zoom level to 13 it gives me black screen with nothing , i don't know what is going on

Comment: i get them from example to mark murphy in android book to make some fixed marks in map beside GPS location marks

Comment: please try the lat lng in googlemaps.com once...just to check whether it is not somehwhere in the middle of the ocean....you can also try to debug and find the lat lng of the loaded location just in case of a programming error...

Comment: yeah i have seen these errors when i tried coding with the google maps api...I did not reslly try debugging these...but i never seen these errors affecting the functionality...try restarting the emulator.